# Searching for the first free index

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I have a big array / list of 1 million id and then I need to find the first free id that can be used . It can be assumed that there are couple modules which refer to this data structure and take an id (  during which  it shall be marked as used ) and then return it later ( shall be marked as free ). 
I want to know what different data structures can be used ? and what algorithm I can use to do this efficiently time and space (seperately).
Please excuse if its already present here, I did search before posting .

Comment: What does first mean in this context?  Do you just need any free ID or the least id (assuming there's a reasonable order), or the first one in your list of IDs?  Each of those would give a different solution.

Comment: Are the 1 millions Id related to something specific or do you just need a unique Id ? If you simply need unique ids, they are libraries that can generate a unique guid on demand with 0 collisions chance assuming some reasonable conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A naive but efficient method would be to store all your ids in a stack.
Getting an id is a constant time operation : pop first item of the list.
When the task is over just push the id on the stack.

If the lowest free id must be returned (and not any free id) you can use a min heap with insertion and pop lowest in O(log N).

Comment: Isn't the cost of reinserting an ID O(n), since you have to scan through the stack to find the right place?

Comment: @templatetypedef No, it should be constant time since all the id in the list are supposed to be free. Just inserting on the top is fine.

Comment: Oh - I think we're interpreting the question differently.  I thought that by "first," the OP meant "lowest," whereas you're interpreting it as "anything that's free."  In that case, this is a great answer!

Comment: @templatetypedef Ah ok I understand more your answer now. I update my answer.

Comment: Looks good, but I think that min-heaps have O(log n)-time pop lowest, rather than O(1) pop lowest.

Comment: @templatetypedef Of course you are right! deleting the min is O(log n).

Comment: Just for clarity , I need the first free entry , so EG: i used 1,2,3,4,5 freed 2 then the first free index would return 2 , because I use linear search here, but this obviously gets ugly when the range of ids is huge. And these approaches just give me an idea about it ! thanks to all. I would keep this thread open for some time till I implement and update which one suits me!

Answer (score 7):

One initial idea that might work would be to store a priority queue of all the unused IDs, sorted so that low IDs are dequeued before high IDs.  Using a standard binary heap, this would make it possible to return an ID to the unused ID pool in O(log n) time and to find the next free ID in O(log n) time as well.  This has the disadvantage that it requires you to explicitly store all of the IDs, which could be space-inefficient if there are a huge number of IDs.

One potential space-saving optimization would be to try to coalesce consecutive ID values into ID ranges.  For example, if you have free IDs 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, and 12, you could just store the ranges 1, 3-6, 8-10, and 12.  This would require you to change the underlying data structure a bit.  Rather than using a binary heap, you could use a balanced binary search tree which stores the ranges.  Since these ranges won't overlap, you can compare the ranges as less than, equal to, or greater than other ranges.  Since BSTs are stored in sorted order, you can find the first free ID by taking the minimum element of the tree (in O(log n) time) and looking at the low end of its range.  You would then update the range to exclude that first element, which might require you to remove an empty range from the the tree.  When returning an ID to the pool of unused IDs, you could do a predecessor and successor search to determine the ranges that come immediately before and after the ID.  If either one of them could be extended to include that ID, you can just extend the range.  (You might need to merge two ranges as well).  This also only takes O(log n) time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the same idea as a sequence object in a database.  It works well.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description, I need to implement the approach you mentioned as the other approaches till Fenwwick tree to see which one can be done with the least complexity / space / time.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use linked list (linked list of id's). Linkup all those list and the head should point to the free list (lets say at init all are free). Whenever the it'll be marked as used, remove it and place it at the end of the list and make the head point to the next free list. In this way, your list will be structured in a manner of "from free to used". You can also get a free list in O(1). Also, when an id is marked as free - put it as the first member of the linked list (as it's become free it's become usable) i.e make head point to this list. Hope this will helps!

Answer (score 0):

Preamble: binary heap seems the best answer indeed. I'll present here an alternative, that may have advantages in some scenarios.

One possible way is to use a [Fenwick Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree). You can store in each position either 0 or 1, indicating that a position was already used or not. And you can find the first empty position with a binary search (to find the first range [1..n] that has sum n-1). The complexity of this operation is O(log^2 n), which is worse than a binary heap, but this approach has another advantages:

- You can implement a Fenwick Tree in less than 10 lines of code
- You can now calculate the density (number of used / total ids) of a range in O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not strictly need the lowest id, you can allocate ids to modules in batches of a 1000. When freeing ids, they can be added to the back of the list. And once in a while you would sort the list, to make sure that again, the ids you assign are from the low end.

Answer (score -1):

Well, an array probably isn't the best structure. An Hash would be better, speedwise at least. As for the structure for each "node", all that I can see you need is just the id, and wether it is being used, or not.

Comment: How would you keep track of the next free ID number?